# Connection between front and and back end | Node.Js , Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

New to the dev world, and am trying to connect my front end and back end, so I can modify the dom to return results in form submission.

Can someone please take a look at the below and let me know if this is acceptable?

Front end:

```
let data = await fetch ("/lookup/:url").then(result => result.json())
```

Back end

```
const express = require('express');
const Kirk = require('Kirk');

const app = express()
const Kirk = new Kirk()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server started on port ${PORT}'));

app.get('/lookup/:url', function (req, res) {
  Kirk.init().then(function () {
    Kirk.open(req.params.url).then(function (site) {
      site.analyze().then(function (results) {
        res.json(results)
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: If you remove all the lines with kirk in, it looks good to me.  Although your `fetch ("/lookup/:url")` looks like an odd url..

Comment: @Keith That is my private NPM library. So I need to keep Kirk in. Any idea on how I can modify the DOM in a form to return the results?